# Funcion compleja de caracteres en mariadb

Tags: mariadb, function

Tengo una base de datos en MariaDB y necesito una función para poder determinar desde una cadena de caracteres si coincide con un tipo de máscara la cual es definida por el usuario. Estoy trabajando en un sistema que tiene artículos, y cada uno esta definido por un código de barra. El problema surge que algunos productos están envasados. Estos tienen en el código el importe y el código del producto en una estructura. Defino a continuación una estructura como ejemplo:

*CÒDIGO*:  20IIIIXXXX9 
*Descripciòn*:

> - Los numeros en este ejemplo, "20";"9", y la cantidad de caracteres (11) que tiene el codigo son fijos.
> - En donde se encuentra el caracter I sera donde se leera el importe
> - En donde se encuentra el caracter X sera el codigo del producto

Un ejemplo del codigo:

*CÒDIGO*: **20033012219**

*Descripcion*:

> - cantidad de caracteres  son 11 igual que la cadena màscara
> - El 20 al principio y el 9 al final tambien coincide porque son fijos
> - El importe seria 3,30 y el ID del producto seria 1221

El ejemplo es bien claro, ahora muestro las bases a las que tengo definidas las base de datos

**Tabla balanzas:**

```
CREATE TABLE `balanzas` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `eliminado` BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=9
;
```

**Tabla codigo de balanza**

```
CREATE TABLE `codigobarrasbalanza` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_balanza` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `estructuradecodigo` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8
;
```

**Ejemplo de funcion**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `codigobalanza_verificar`(
    `codigo` TEXT

)
RETURNS binary(1)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

SET cantidad = (select id  FROM codigobarrasbalanza WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(codigo) = CHAR_LENGTH(estructuradecodigo));

return true;
END
```

Como se puede ver, la funcion "Char_length" es la que podria empezar para verificar si existe la conicidencia de largo del codigo, junto a al codigo consultado.
Lo que quiero determinar si es que pertenece a un codigo de balanza, y si es asi, obtener los valores de importe y el ID de producto. Existen funciones en mysql que puedan ayudarme en esto? espero respuesta gracias!

PD: Algo que puede ayudar creo yo.. es REGEXP, aqui dejo un [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regular-expressions-overview/#character-classes)

Comment: mysql es un gestor muy aparte de lo que es MariaDB, te invito a leer https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3848/qu%C3%A9-hacer-con-preguntas-mariadb-con-etiquetas-de-mysql/3849#3849 para que no uses ambos nombres cuando solo te estés refiriendo a una tecnología de las 2 en cuestión

Comment: Ya lo corregí muchas gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para el que le suceda lo mismo aquí encontré la solución a la problemática. El siguiente es el código de la función que necesitaba:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `codigobalanza_verificar`(
    `codigo` TEXT
)
RETURNS tinyint(1)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE cantidad int(11);
SET cantidad = (select id  FROM codigobarrasbalanza WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(codigo) = CHAR_LENGTH(estructuradecodigo) AND codigo  REGEXP  replace(replace(replace(estructuradecodigo,'I','.'),'X','.'),'P','.')LIMIT 1);
IF cantidad != 0 OR cantidad != -1 THEN
return true;
ELSE
return false;
END IF;
END
```

Utilice la función REGEXP con el carácter "." Que sirve para poder comparar el código mascara con un código.
Espero que le sea útil a alguien!